# How to bypass JDBCTemplate org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, sql-insert, jdbctemplate

I am working with SpringBoot and jdbc template and performing bulk inset where getting some duplicate data. I want to ignore the duplicate row and system should continue the insertion but I am getting exception and insertion is rolled back. How can i proceed with data insertion keeping duplicate row aside.

Using below code to insert.

```
    jdbcTemplate.execute(insertCommand);
```

Comment: Check data if not exist -> insert or you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` for your insertCommand (Update last update by)
P/s: should not use INSERT IGNORE ...., not only duplicated key ignored

Comment: INSERT IF NOT EXISTS is the best approach. However, I would have a vague solution here. That would be in your transactional annotation, you can use dontrollbackon parameter. For example @Transactional(dontRollbackOn = DuplicateKeyException.class). I have not tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SQL which will do nothing on duplicate key entry

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE key_column = key_column
```